# Why does JavaScript ES6 function calls would not work as expected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The following snipped is given:

```
function output() {
  return "<p>normal function</p>";  
}

//first version
document.write(output());
//second version
document.write(() => {return "<p>arrow-function</p>"});
```

I was wondering, why a normal function would print correctly in the example above, but the second approach would just print the translated function declaration like that:

```
"function () {return "

arrow-function
";} "
```

Can you explain me that?

Comment: You are writing the method, and not the result of the method, like you do with `output()`. To make it work, you'll need to invoke the arrow function `document.write((() => {return "<p>arrow-function</p>"})())` would work.

Comment: Anyway: I've just came back here and see all the answers and comments now which must be happened within the last few minutes. So you really should calm down since I've not voted anything yet @jfadich

Comment: There are a lot of helpful and correct answers below - I had to select one so I chose the one which has the best quality in formatting and has the most extensive explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually invoking the second function as you are with the first. If you wrap the function and invoke it you'll get the expected result.

```js
function output() {
  return "<p>normal function</p>";  
}

//first version
document.write(output());
//second version
document.write(() => {return "<p>arrow-function</p>"});

//should be
document.write((() => {return "<p>arrow-function</p>"})());
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are creating the function but not calling it.

To call the anonymous arrow function you should do:

```
(() => {return "<p>arrow-function</p>"})()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are telling `document.write` to output a function definition that you are passing and you aren't really calling that arrow function so it isn't returning a value. You could do this instead and get the results you are expecting

```
var f = () => {return "<p>arrow-function</p>"};

document.write(f())
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because the first parameter is a **function call**, whereas the second is **only a function**.

For the second call to work as the first, you would do:

```
document.write( (() => {return "<p>arrow-function</p>"})() );
```

This syntax above is pretty messy: you need the extra () to **call** the function. On top of that, you need to surround all the arrow function definition within parentheses due to language syntax requirements.

This way to immediately call functions from the very definition was really popular before ES2015 [and is known as IIFE's](https://medium.com/@vvkchandra/essential-javascript-mastering-immediately-invoked-function-expressions-67791338ddc6). You usually see it with `function` statements but you can immediately call arrow functions too.

On the other hand, for the first line of your snippet to work as your original second, you would do instead:

```
document.write(output);
```

So now you're passing just two function **definitions** to `document.write`.